# Difference between fuse diode and diode - is there is any?

Tags: diodes

I have a BSA motorcycle with a couple of lucas 1 and 2 amp diodes in the electrics. It is hard to find the original 2 amp lucas diodes so I am thinking of using a standard 2 amp fuse diode instead. What is the difference between a diode and a fuse diode. I am thinking a fuse diode fails safely if overloaded with current whereas with an ordinary diode the whole circuit will get hot and possibly burn out the wire in any random place. Or is there no difference between the two.

Comment: Can you explain or give examples of what "lucas diode" and "fuse diode" are? Is this some motorbike jargon?

Comment: You would have to give us part numbers, and ideally a circuit diagram too - it could be that the diodes made by Lucas are Zener diodes.

Comment: @Justme Apparently, a "fuse diode" is a diode packaged as an automotive blade fuse.

Comment: A fuse diode is a diode that blows when you need the lights. Available from Lucas, the Prince of Darkness.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. The diodes are in place because the magneto produces AC current and the lights need DC power from a battery. The diodes protect the battery. My question was only about whether there is any material difference between a "fuse" diode and a diode. Presumably the "fuse" diode blows out safely under current overload whereas the non-fuse type burns out in an uncontrolled manner, ie anywhere in the circuit? Or  are all diodes fuse diodes and we are just talking about the same thing.

Comment: Andrew Morton, thanks for your comment. It is not a zener diode.

Comment: The part number for the Lucas 1 Amp diode is RD953048 (83205 83225)

Comment: If the lights are incandescent bulbs, they willl be happy with AC. The contacts on the way to the bulbs are likely to be happier with AC rather than DC. Maybe you should delete the question from here and instead ask over on [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/), although I suspect that a lack of research on your part could be met with derision.

Comment: Andrew Morton. This BSA has some lights powered by DC current from a battery. Other lights are powered from the AC generator. The generator charges the battery and the diodes are there to change AC to DC for that purpose. I am on this page to ask if there is such a thing as a fuse diode or not. Thats all. Do they exist?

Comment: I have now managed to buy one of these 2 amp"fuse" diodes.I have tested it and confirmed it is a diode and not just a fuse. It is a two blade type and I can see part number 1N5960. Is there likely to be any difference between this and the Lucas 2 amp diode which is not a "fuse" diode as far as i am aware. Thank you for any comments.